# aws web app error after deleting rds instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, drupal, rds

I am developing website on aws instance with drupal 7 web app, and it is connected to the aws's mysql server (rds).

I deleted my rds instance "my-db-instance" few days ago, and now my drupal web app running on my ec2 instance is giving me this error.

**PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'my-db-instance.cnzzdhtcyxjs.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (2) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /var/www/html/includes/lock.inc).**

'my-db-instance.cnzzdhtcyxjs.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' is my deleted rds instance network address.

How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after delete the rds, did you create a new one and restore the database to new RDS mysql?

Not sure which application you are running, you need find out the config file and replace the rds name `my-db-instance.cnzzdhtcyxjs.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` with new rds.

Comment: Thanks. I replace the rds at /sites/default/settings.php!